# Django global name 'PageNotAnInteger' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have a strange issue. I have a view that is returning some JSON through a serializer and paginator from Django REST Framework.

My view looks like this (returning all objects in the Countries model):

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def country_list(request):
    """
    List all countries
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':

        geoname_ids = request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('geoname_ids')
        queryset = Countries.objects.all()
        paginator = Paginator(queryset, request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('limit'))
        page = request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('page')

        try:
            countries = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            #If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
            countries = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            #If page is out of range
            #Delivery last page of results
            countries = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        serializer_context = {'request': request}
        serializer = PaginatedCountrySerializer(countries, context=serializer_context)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This works fine.

However I need to return a country with a specific ID, I am trying this:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def country_list(request):
    """
    List all countries
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':

        geoname_ids = request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('geoname_ids')
        queryset = Countries.objects.filter(country_geoname_id=geoname_ids)
        paginator = Paginator(queryset, request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('limit'))
        page = request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('page')

        try:
            countries = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            #If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
            countries = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            #If page is out of range
            #Delivery last page of results
            countries = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        serializer_context = {'request': request}
        serializer = PaginatedCountrySerializer(countries, context=serializer_context)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

And this I obviously call the URL with the geonames_ids parameter. It gives an error: `global name 'PageNotAnInteger' is not defined` referring to then exception.

Is something wrong with my code? It doesn't make sense why PageNotAnInteger would work find before changing the queryset.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should import it first:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not use PageNotAnInteger without importing it.
So please import it first.

```
from django.core.paginator import PageNotAnInteger
```

If you need EmptyPage as well:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
```